# Opencart Добавить products перед ЧПУ товара

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

сейчас ЧПУ товара так:
site.com/link_product

нужно
site.com/products/link_product

да, знаю что можно создать такую категорию и появится products, но я убрал ссылки все категории из карточки товара
http://joxi.ru/V2VOyk9tGMOolA

не зависимо от категории, фильтр или поиска, ЧПУ товара всегда был таким
site.com/products/link_product